# Comparing dates using datetime from a different calendar year

Tags: python, date, datetime

If I try to compare dates in the form  "Month Year" and the year is different, the month difference won't be correct. If I compare January 2016 to March 2017 the month difference will be 3 and not 14. Is there a way I can put months to 0 when the year increases.

```
import datetime

month_names = ["January",   "February", "March",    "April",
           "May",       "June",     "July",     "August",
           "September", "October",  "November", "December"]

months = {name : (index + 1) for index, name in enumerate(month_names)}

current_month    = datetime.date.today().strftime('%B')
month_joined     = input("Please enter the month you joined: ")
month_difference = abs(months[current_month] - months[month_joined])

current_year = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%Y'))
year_joined = int(input('Please enter the year you joined: '))

year_due = year_joined + 1

year_difference = current_year - year_due
```

The month difference does not take into accound the difference in years. I have tried a few solutions to ignore an input for month difference and put 12 months in for each year. I need the month difference to be exact. Any ideas? I'm stumped.

Comment: When it comes to dates, I cheat and use partedatetime. Then you can create dates with human readable text such as cal.parse("last January at 5pm") -- makes life so, so much easier.

Comment: How do you expect to calculate the difference correctly when you do not even know year_joined when calculating month_difference?

Comment: @SteveJ Its isn't a library and I can't find a way to use it to print the current month. What even is it?

Comment: @larwa1n Yes but how would I use the year as well to calculate the month difference? Can year be equal to 12 months? That is what I need help with. How would I use both?

Comment: @Jack; yes, it is a package; https://pypi.python.org/pypi/parsedatetime/ You can read more about it in the free ebook; http://www.oreilly.com/programming/free/20-python-libraries-you-arent-using-but-should.csp  (I'm in no way affiliated with oreilly or parsedatetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by 'put months to 0' but you can add `year_difference * 12` to `month_difference` to map March 2017 to Jan 2016 as described.